# Is there a way to preview with dark mode AND have .sizeThatFits?

Tags: swiftui, preview

Whenever I add a dark mode preview in the group, the .sizeThatFits attribute is ignored. So my light mode preview (my default) shows in a trimmed size, but the dark mode preview shows a full device image.

Doesn't seem to matter what order I put the attributes for the 2nd view in the group:

```
Group {
   MyView()
      .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)

   MyView()
      .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
      .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
      .previewDisplayName("Dark Mode")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: Preview]

As @Asperi stated, when displaying a dark colour scheme, you should preferably use `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)`. Also, order matters in SwiftUI.

```
Group {
   MyView()

   MyView()
      .preferredColorScheme(.dark) 
      .previewDisplayName("Dark Mode")
}
.previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead preferred color scheme, like

```
static var previews: some View {
    YourView()
      .preferredColorScheme(.dark)     // << here !!
      .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4

[image: demo]

Comment: Try putting that into a Group like I describe in my updated question. I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.